# python pandas and locate values

Tags: python, pandas, locate

Let's say I've a DataSerie like this :

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(4,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
df['test'] = ['A','B','A','C']
```

I would like to extract the lines with the 'A' letter and retrieve the values of a Serie, let's say 'C' column. How is it possible to do this whitouh looping into the serie ?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
df[df['test'].str.contains('A')]['C']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas filtering:

```
df[df["test"].str.contains("A")]["C"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If equal to 'A' is what you need

```
df.loc[df.test.eq('A'), 'C']
```

Otherwise

```
df.loc[df.test.str.contains('A'), 'C']
```